# “bird nest” vs. “birds’ nest”

Tags: grammatical-number, compounds

[image]

Shouldn’t the word *bird* in the first sentence be *birds’* as it’s a nest for more than one?

Comment: How many donkeys would there be in a _donkey sanctuary_? Actually, the convention varies hereabouts ... _dogs home_ uses the plural attributive noun. But attributive nouns are usually singular, even when it doesn't appear the logical choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn’t the word *bird* in the first sentence be *birds’* as it’s a nest for more than one?

You could use *birds’* here, making it a [genitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case), but *bird nest* is something else, namely a [compound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound). Now in the English language, the default grammatical number for the first part of a compound is singular. For example, a car park usually contains more than one car and an ant hill contains more than one ant.

Comment: Very true, Wrzlprmft, but both the genitive / attributive choice and the default choice for attributive nouns (with exceptions) have been covered here before. Several times.

Comment: But people don't say *bird nest* do they? Unless perhaps they are talking about the soup... *bird-nest soup*?

Comment: I've only heard about *birds-nest* soup.